# UIBezierPath has only half stroke

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

When I try to draw a shape like below with the following codes, the shape only shows half stroke line.

[image]

```
let shape = SKShapeNode()
            shape.path = createPointerPath().cgPath
            shape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
            shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.439, blue: 0.678, alpha: 1.0)
            shape.strokeColor = .white
            shape.lineWidth = 2
            addChild(shape)
```

Create shape:

```
func createPointerPath() -> UIBezierPath {

    let pointerPath = UIBezierPath()
    pointerPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))

    pointerPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:100), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:-10, y:0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:-50, y:100))
    pointerPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:50, y:100), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:10, y:0))

    pointerPath.stroke()        
    pointerPath.close()
    return pointerPath
}
```

If I set x to 10, it shows another half stroe line, but the shape is not closed.

```
    pointerPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:10, y:0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:50, y:100), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:10, y:0))
```

[image]

Any suggestion? Thx!

Comment: I can't reproduce this with just the `createPointerPath()` code. I suspect the bug is elsewhere. How are you drawing the inner fill and outer color? The issue may be there.

Comment: Side note: you generally shouldn't call `.stroke` in the middle of a function that returns a path. That draws into the current context if there is one. You generally should let the caller handle stroking the path. (In fact, it's possible that's part of your problem if you're adding more to this path after you return it.)

Comment: @RobNapier the shape is added as SKShapeNode, I supplemented the codes, pls have a look again.

Comment: I would definitely take that `.stroke` out.

Comment: @RobNapier yes, the warnings disappeared when .stroke removed, but it still shows half stroke :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i got after trying; hope it helps you

```
    let v : UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200))
    v.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = createPointerPath().cgPath
    shape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.439, blue: 0.678, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    v.layer.addSublayer(shape)
    self.addSubview(v)
```

It's same func you have gave:

```
func createPointerPath() -> UIBezierPath {

    let pointerPath = UIBezierPath()
    pointerPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))

    pointerPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:100), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:-10, y:0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:-50, y:100))
    pointerPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:50, y:100), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:10, y:0))

    pointerPath.stroke()
    pointerPath.close()
    return pointerPath
}
```

Output:

[image: Output of Above Code]

Comment: yes, it works perfect in CAShapeLayer. Did I miss something in SKShapeNode?

Comment: can i suggest what may change!! @jdleung Why SKShapeNode? which swift version u r using?

Comment: I need to add it as SKShapeNode so that it can be move. and not only one shape, there will be more than 10 same shapes. Im using Swift 3.0, Xcode latest version. Can you make it works in SKShapeNode?

Comment: I finally make it works by changing the x or y to 0.1, but not 0 as the first curve. This may be not the right solution, but it works.